# Suspected virus on Wireshark, but antivirus didn't detect it

Tags: virus

I tried Kasparsky and AVG, which didn't find the virus. Tried "search and destroy", which is anti spyware, that found stuff, but didn't remove the virus.

I think there is a virus on the computer. So lunched the wire shark and analyzed the results:

Which a TCP stream that yield :

```
Accept: image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave-flash, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, application/x-ms-application, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-xpsdocument, application/xaml+xml, */*

Referer: http://www.socialnewsworld.com/index.php?aff_id=20196  
Accept-Language: en-us    
UA-CPU: x86    
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 01 Aug 2012 07:16:27 GMT; length=4500    
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; BTRS27025; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)

Host: ad.globe7.com    
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.0 200 OK

Date: Wed, 01 Aug 2012 16:47:54 GMT
Server: YTS/1.19.11
X-RightMedia-Hostname: raptor0510.rm.ch1
P3P: policyref="/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="NOI DSP COR NID CURa ADMa DEVa PSAa PSDa OUR BUS COM INT OTC PUR STA"

Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0    
Vary: *
Last-Modified: Wed, 01 Aug 2012 16:47:54 GMT
Expires: Wed, 01 Aug 2012 16:47:54 GMT
Pragma: no-cache

Content-Length: 4500
Age: 0

Connection: close

<html><head></head><body><script type="text/javascript">/* All portions of this software are copyright (c) 2003-2006 Right Media*/var rm_ban_flash=0;var rm_url="";var rm_pop_frequency=0;var rm_pop_id=0;var rm_pop_times=0;var rm_pop_nofreqcap=0;var rm_passback=0;var rm_tag_type="";rm_tag_type = "iframe"; rm_url = "http://ad.globe7.com/imp?Z=300x250&s=2796686&T=3&_salt=1910561499";var RM_POP_COOKIE_NAME='ym_pop_freq';var RM_INT_COOKIE_NAME='ym_int_freq';if(!window.rm_crex_data){rm_crex_data=new Array();}if(rm_passback==0){rm_pb_data=new Array();if(rm_crex_data.length>0){rm_url+="&X=";for(var i=0;i<rm_crex_data.length;i++){rm_url+=rm_crex_data[i];if(i!=rm_crex_data.length-1){rm_url+=",";}}}}else{rm_pb_data.push(rm_crex_data.pop());rm_url+="&X=";for(var i=0;i<rm_pb_data.length;i++){rm_url+=rm_pb_data[i];if(i!=rm_pb_data.length-1){rm_url+=",";}}rm_url+="&Y=pb";}var flash=new Object();flash=flashDetection();if(cookiesEnabled()){rm_url+=(flash.installed?"&B=10":"&B=12");}else{rm_url+=(flash.installed?"&B=11":"&B=13");}if(!flash.installed||rm_ban_flash==1){rm_url+="&m=2";}if(rm_url.indexOf("&u=")==-1){var url='';try{if(rm_tag_type=="ad"){if(top==self){url=encodeURIComponent(top.location.href);url=url.substr(0,256);rm_url+="&u="+url;}}else if(rm_tag_type=="iframe"){url=encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);url=url.substr(0,256);rm_url+="&u="+url;}}catch(e){}}if(top==self){rm_url+="&r=1";}else{rm_url+="&r=0";}var rm_tag_src='<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" SRC="'+rm_url+'"><\/SCRIPT>';if(rm_pop_frequency){if(rmCanShowPop(rm_pop_id,rm_pop_times,rm_pop_frequency)||rm_pop_nofreqcap){document.write(rm_tag_src);}}else{document.write(rm_tag_src);}function cookiesEnabled(){var cookieEnabled=(navigator.cookieEnabled)?true:false;if(typeof navigator.cookieEnabled=="undefined"&&!cookieEnabled){document.cookie="testcookie";cookieEnabled=(document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie")!=-1)?true:false;}return cookieEnabled;}function rmGetCookie(Name){var search=Name+"=";var CookieString=document.cookie;var result=null;if(CookieString.length>0){offset=CookieString.indexOf(search);if(offset!=-1){offset+=search.length;end=CookieString.indexOf(";",offset);if(end==-1){end=CookieString.length;}result=unescape(CookieString.substring(offset,end));}}return result;}function flashDetection(){var flash=new Object();flash.installed=false;flash.version='0.0';if(navigator.plugins&&navigator.plugins.length){for(x=0;x<navigator.plugins.length;x++){if(navigator.plugins[x].name.indexOf('Shockwave Flash')!=-1){flash.version=navigator.plugins[x].description.split('Shockwave Flash ')[1];flash.installed=true;break;}}}else if(window.ActiveXObject){for(x=2;x<10;x++){try{oFlash=eval("new ActiveXObject('ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash."+x+"');");if(oFlash){flash.installed=true;flash.version=x+'.0';}}catch(e){}}}return flash;}function rmReplace(myString,toReplace,replaceBy){return(myString.replace(new RegExp(toReplace,'gi'),replaceBy));}function writeCookie(ckName,ckVal){var numdays=14;var today=new Date();var expires=new Date();expires.setTime(today.getTime()+(1000*60*60*24*numdays));var cookieText=ckName+"="+ckVal+";expires="+expires.toGMTString()+";path=/;";document.cookie=cookieText;return null;}function rmCanShowPop(rm_pop_id,pop_times,pop_frequency){var countCookieName=RM_POP_COOKIE_NAME+rm_pop_id;var expireCookieName=RM_POP_COOKIE_NAME+"_expiration"+rm_pop_id;var shownTimes=rmGetCookie(countCookieName);if(shownTimes==null){rmWriteExpirationCookie(expireCookieName,pop_frequency);shownTimes=0;}else{shownTimes=Number(shownTimes);}if(shownTimes<pop_times){shownTimes=1+shownTimes;var expiration=rmGetCookie(expireCookieName);rmWritePopFrequencyCookie(rm_pop_id,shownTimes,expiration);return_value=true;}else{return_value=false;}return return_value;}function rmWritePopFrequencyCookie(rm_pop_id,shownTimes,expiration){var cookieName=RM_POP_COOKIE_NAME+rm_pop_id;var cookieText=cookieName+"="+shownTimes+";"+"expires="+expiration+";path=/;";document.cookie=cookieText;}function rmWriteExpirationCookie(cookieName,frequency){var today=new Date();var expires=new Date();expires.setTime(today.getTime()+(1000*frequency));var cookieText=cookieName+"="+expires.toGMTString()+";"+"expires="+expires.toGMTString()+";path=/;";document.cookie=cookieText;}</script><noscript><a href="http://ad.globe7.com/imageclick?Z=300x250&s=2796686&T=3&_salt=1910561499&t=2" target="_parent"><img border="0" src="http://ad.globe7.com/imp?Z=300x250&s=2796686&T=3&_salt=1910561499&t=2"></img></a></noscript></body></html>
```

That is a popup virus. If you save the

```
html to /html
```

in

```
file.html
```

And open it in browser you see it. Now, my question is, how do I further detect where the virus is and how to remove it from the system?  Running on Windows XP SP3

Comment: In addition to cleaning up the spelling and formatting, it would help if you could provide more information.  What kind of OS are you running? What symptoms lead you to beleive there's a virus? A web based threat like a "pop up virus" is going to present differently than a trojan or worm that's actually on your computer.

Answer (score 4):

The one any only true answer to removing a virus from a computer: "Nuke it from orbit, it's the only way to be sure". Which roughly translates to wiping and reinstalling. You may want to take an offline image of the machine first so you can recover important files and such.

Once a system in comporomised you can never trust it again. You don't know if the virus is still there, or what it has changed; you can't trust utilities to remove virii, they are meant to prevent, not remove.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth trying [combofix](http://www.combofix.org/) and [mbam](http://www.malwarebytes.org/), both fairly capable malware cleaners, the first being the most thorough.